# How to check a List for a match in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, if-statement

Assuming:

```
strings = ["abc", "a", "bc"]
str = "bc"
```

I want to:

```
{% if str is in strings %}
```

Doesn't look like this is allowed in Django.  If not what is the proper syntax or a method for checking a value in a List?

Comment: How do I add a bounty to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an app running on Google App Engine.  Here is a custom filter that will do the trick:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from django import template as django_template

def in_list(value, arg):
  """
  Given an item and a list, check if the item is in the list.
  Usage:
  {% if item|in_list:list %} 
      in list 
  {% else %} 
      not in list
  {% endif %}
  """
  return value in arg

register = template.create_template_register()  
ifinlist = register.filter(in_list)
```

Comment: This worked for me when I checked in the template for nulls passing in and used "@register.filter" above the method. I didn't need the last two lines

Answer (score 1):

Programmers don't like extra words. Try:

```
{% if str in strings %}
```

Comment: raise TemplateSyntaxError, "'if' statement improperly formatted".

Comment: @Will Merydith, @Greg Hewgill: work only for djnago 1.2 : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#smart-if-tag